# A constructible type deriving from dbContext could not be found in the selected file (EF Power Tools Beta 3 + VS 2010 SP1)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I get this error every time trying to use the View Entity Data Model Function. There is nothing to be found on this issue for my constellation (VS 2010 SP1, Power Tools Beta 3). What I've already tried:

- completely reinstalled VS 2010
- installed VS 2010 on freshly installed W7P64 machine

doesn't help. Microsoft says that this error could be occur when using VS 2011 (never heard about!) and the solution was to delete some registry key. Unfortunately there is no such registry key on my machine.

Does anyone has an idea how to get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solve this problem by upgrading the installation of MVC version 
I would suggest you to install ASP MVC3, If you your project is on MVC3 The links is
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3.

Or If your project is in ASP MVC 4 then use this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: To check please use new project and create new class.